# How can I make a hard drive copy its contents to another hard drive in real time?

Tags: file-transfer, file-management, storage

I'm using an old pc as a storage space and I have two 2TB HDD drives. I want to use them in a way that when I place a file or a picture in hard drive 1, the same files are saved in hard drive 2 in real time. How can I do that?

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows 2000 and higher can create a software mirrored partition.

Comment: I'm about to write you an answer on how to do this on windows. I will be using windows 10 in my example, but the screens haven't changed much since 2000 and 2000 will likely perform well on your old pc.

Comment: It is possible the answers so far, which involve mirroring, are not what you want.  Mirroring is a reliability feature, but the user sees only one file system.  Only if you remove the "copy" hard drive from the mirror  (RAID set) do you see the same file in two different places.  And then of course the copies won't happen.  So if you want to have the same file appear in two different places (e.g., two different file systems) or on one permanent (installed) drive and one removable drive ... you'll need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Raid mirroring of the drives (RAID 1) would accomplish this easily, there are other ways however I'm not familiar enough with them to attempt to explain how to manage it.

Comment: Although this is technically correct, the fact that he mentions its an old pc makes me assume the pc does not have a RAID controller, and thus this is not possible.

Comment: If he installs a Linux then he can create a software raid... perfectly achievable on an old PC... and free...

Comment: How can I do that in Linux? What do i need?

Comment: Windows 2000 and higher also offer this

Comment: @LPChip: Perhaps not real hardware RAID, no, but my previous desktop from 2006-ish had _two_ FakeRAID chips [though I hadn't used them]; it's a relatively cheap feature, since the OS driver ends up doing all the work anyway.

Comment: @Joshua: For modern filesystem-level RAID, either zfs or btrfs; for traditional disk-level RAID, either mdadm or dmraid.

Comment: @Joshua In Linux, you make do software raid with the `mdadm`command http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/08/mdadm-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @Joshua Please edit your post to include system specs (including chiefly motherboard, CPU, drive identifications) and preferred OS to avoid future users having to guess and possibly posting non-applicable answers.

Answer (score 14):

If you use Windows 2000 or up, you can create 1 mirrored partition that spans 2 or more drives, where data written to this one partition is stored on those disks simultaneously.

In order to do this, go to `Control Panel` > `Administrative Tools` > `Computer Management`.

Open `Disk Management`[image]

Depending on which OS version you are using, you may need to convert the disk to a Dynamic disk. If New Mirrored volume is missing or greyed out, convert, otherwise skip this step.

[image]

Now, Right click one of the empty disks, and choose New Mirrored Volume...

[image]

Select the other disk and press Add... then Next.

[image]

Assign a drive letter to this new partition and press next.

In the next screen you can choose the volume name and type of the partition. Change if you want, or leave it with the default settings. Using NTFS is recommended. Then press Next, and finish.

[image]

Comment: I've heard that this implementation is quite slow however, even compared to other kinds of software RAID. Even Windows 10's "Storage Spaces" are said to have better performance.

Comment: @grawity I'm using this setup and it outperforms a normal setup. Okay, it is likely not going to be as fast as a raid controller. I haven't actually tested that as I was not able to utilize this.

Comment: Also, if OP is already on windows, this is by far the easiest way to get results.

Answer (score 0):

*RAID* does allow that, but it needs dedicated additional hardware (controllers); another option is *Shadow Copy*, which is a Windows feature.

Google those key words for details and conditions, there is a lit of information to know.

Comment: Can you name the hardware needed please?

Comment: RAID controller ;)

Comment: Downvoting for false info.  As noted above, software-based RAID exists.  This will require no additional hardware such as specialized RAID controllers.  Such RAID controller functionality is also built into some motherboards/BIOS/whatever.  The primary reason why additional hardware is often used for RAID has more to do with specialization benefits, such as enhanced speed (and maybe safety features, like a batter and speaker that alerts when a drive drops), not because extra hardware is frequently an actual requirement to make this technically work.

Comment: My 5-year-old motherboard has RAID support built in, OP may not need additional hardware.